# How to upload stuff to Amazon EC2 Windows instance?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, virtual-machines, cloud-computing

I've never used Amazon EC2 - I am thinking to test a few instances for running intensive computation processes I have a requirement for rather than buying real hardware.

I am given to understand the thing is quite easy to setup - but I have no clue of how it actually works, in terms of transferring data to my ec2 instances.

So the question is **how can I upload stuff to my instance?**

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved by sharing my drives when establishing remote connection. Smooth!

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your assets on to an S3 bucket and then have your instances download appropriate items from there.

Answer (score 0):

I found that dropbox is the quickest and easiest way to do this, as long as you don't have any concerns about your data being on the dropbox servers.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I start a WinSSHD(22) instance on the server and then open the Windows Firewall and the Amazon Firewall to both allow the port through.  I trust it more than Windows SMB.  Also, Dropbox works but has the 2GB limit (or whatever).

With the Tunnelier client for WinSSHD I get telnet, RDP, and FTP all tunneled through the single port 22 with SSH.

If you have a Linux instance with SSHD 5.x or higher, you can do the same thing using WinSCP as the client (or Tunnelier).